# WikiData property update using Python

Tags: python, wikidata, wikidata-api

I am trying to update an existing wikidata property programatically using Python. Currently I am using wikidataintegrator and here is example code :

```
# obtaining the wikidata item directly from WikiData
item = wdi_core.WDItemEngine(wd_item_id=<some_id_here>)

# I can create a property via the wikidataintegrator python api
#create property
prop = wdi_core.WDString(value="some_string_value", prop_nr=<property_id>)
```

So my question here is how can I update the specific property in the current item ?

Comment: Is this not the kind of information which is usually found in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find it there ...